# Can a variable be used in the name of a file being included in php?

Tags: php, syntax, include, concatenation

I am trying to include different header files based on the variable passed from another page. The variable is $section. Here is my code:

```
 <?php include("header".$section.".php"); ?>
```

I am trying to include headerAbout.php or headerMenu.php or.... based on the variable $section. But I am getting an error:

```
 include(header.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I dont know why the variable is not being concatenated. can someone clarify this?

Comment: What happens when you do a `var_dump` on `$section`?

Comment: just put echo for that variable, weather it get value or not?

Comment: I am sorry. I found out the mistake. Kindly refer to my comment below.

Comment: Consider path traversal exploits if you take that $section as raw URL parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that it's not being concatenated, the variable's not defined at the point you try to use it in the include. Where are you setting its value?

Comment: I found out the problem. I was previewing it from firefox directly and it does not give any value to the url variable. Hence the value for the variable for $section was not being set. If I give the value in the url, its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [`include` language construct](http://php.net/include) just expects a [string](http://php.net/language.types.string) as parameter value. This string value can either be from a string literal, a [variable](http://php.net/language.variables)/[constant](http://php.net/language.constants) or any other expression that returns a string (e.g. function/method calls).

The cause of your error is probably that `$section` doesn’t contain a value you are expecting.

Note that you should be aware that if you allow user input to be part of the file location you might be vulnerable to [path traversal attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal). So make sure to validate the value.

Comment: Thank you. Kindly refer to my comment.

Answer (score 1):

It is working correctly. Its likely that `$section` does not contain a value in the current scope or at that point in execution.

Comment: Thank you. Kindly refer to my comment.